Issues with Audio Amplifier Circuit - No Output Signal with Capacitor, noise
I'm having trouble with an audio amplifier circuit that I designed, and I hope someone can help me figure out what's wrong.
Here's the schematic of my circuit:

Rsig is a variable resistor
The circuit is supposed to amplify an audio signal, but I'm not getting any output signal at RL when I connect through capacitor C6 (2200uF). However, when I replace the capacitor C6, I can hear a loud and distorted sound. I've already tried replacing C6 with new one and 1000uF and checking all connections, but the issue persists.
Additionally, when I connect the speaker through a 330uF capacitor to the emitter of Q3, I can hear the sound loudly but it is still distorted.
Could anyone provide some insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Any advice on how to properly troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Can R2 (49 ohm) dissipate 3 W of heat? What is the voltage across R2?

check DC values. Junction R7/8, Q5/6 base, q# emitter, and so on. Are they as expected? (when you have "not working" analogue circuits, always start by verifying DC conditions.)

I'm not sure how you expect Q2/Q3 to work, but with just a pullup resistor to the base they're going to be turned on all the time. Only the largest of negative signal peaks are going to produce a change in the output and an audible signal at the emitter of Q3, so it's going to be heavily distorted.
Determine a sensible bias point and try again. You could even get rid of C3 and DC couple it to the previous stage.
I'm not sure why you feel you need such a high current gain from Q2/Q3 and such a low emitter resistance, which will create a huge quiescent current draw and dissipate a great deal of power.
As for troubleshooting, an oscilloscope is invaluable once it's built but a simple run with a simulator would be a quick and easy way to test things out before you go that far.

stream of consciousness on problems

I'm having trouble with an audio amplifier circuit that I designed,
and I hope someone can help me figure out what's wrong.

In order of badness (and this isn't a complete list):

\$Q_2+Q_3\$ emitter follower stage is single-quadrant. \$R_2\$ supplies the other needed quadrant. \$R_2\$ must be insanely low-valued (and running very hot and wasteful) to make the stage somewhat useful. Even then, it cannot ever run correctly.

\$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ are way under-powered. At maximum output swing, of say \$\pm4\:\text{V}\$, the base of \$Q_5\$ may be within \$1\:\text{V}\$ of the upper rail. Which means only \$1\:\text{V}\$ across \$R_5\$ then. But the worst case \$\beta\$ for \$Q_5\$ is \$30\$. So there needs to be, worst case, \$16\frac23\:\text{mA}\$ through \$R_5\$ and therefore \$R_5\$ needs to be less than \$60\:\Omega\$. This is a terribly wasteful design for the output stage.
As you currently have it, with \$750\:\Omega\$ resistors, they may need to drop \$12\:\text{V}\$ in order to supply the necessary current!
With \$+4\:\text{V}\$ across \$R_\text{L}\$, you are at \$+10\:\text{V}\$ at the junction of \$R_7\$ and \$R_8\$ and therefore at least \$+10\:\text{V}+100\:\text{mV}+800\:\text{mV}=+10.9\:\text{V}\$ at the base of \$Q_5\$. But it will need \$\frac1{\beta=30}\frac{+4\:\text{V}}{8\:\Omega}=16\frac23\:\text{mA}\$, all of which must come through \$R_5\$.
Multiply that out and see what I mean!
You could just say that the output stage won't be asked for that much. But how much works?
Well, \$\frac{12\:\text{V}-10.9\:\text{V}}{750\:\Omega}\cdot\left(\beta=30\right)\cdot\left(R_\text{L}=8\:\Omega\right)\approx 350\:\text{mV}\$ peak. Is that what you want out of this stage? If so, this means your input cannot be more than \$\frac{350\:\text{mV}}{A_v=\frac{5.6\:\text{k}\Omega}{150\:\Omega+26\:\Omega}}=11\:\text{mV}\$ peak.
I don't think this is what you are shooting for.

The prior point also means that there will be significant current variation through the VBE multiplier, depending upon whether \$Q_5\$ or \$Q_6\$ is active. VBE multipliers aren't arranged to handle widely varying currents. Ideally, they should be driven with a constant current.

There's about \$150\:\text{mV}\$, quiescent DC, across \$R_{{\text{E}_1}}\$, but assuming you want maximum output across \$R_{\text{L}}\$ (you won't get that -- see above), this means the input source may need to be allowed as much as \$\pm125\:\text{mV}\$, or \$250\:\text{mV}\$ peak-to-peak. The signal-driven variation will mean some distortion in the \$Q_1\$ stage with such high-valued input signals. And there's no global NFB in the circuit that would be needed to correct this problem.
(But it's not all that serious as it's already the case that this schematic cannot drive the load to such peak values.)


If you want to keep this simple, then you will use a class-A design, which can be done with as few as three BJTs. But it's also very wasteful. Since you are already showing an interest in VBE multipliers and a class-AB output stage and have built up something like this, I'll discount the idea of class-A and continue with the class-AB approach.
my guesses about goals
Let's write down what I can see and infer from your schematic:

Single-rail \$+12\:\text{V}\$ power supply.
\$8\:\Omega\$ load (speaker, I assume.)
class-AB output stage.
\$A_v\approx 30\$.
Power output transistors are TIP41 and TIP42, since you have them.

What I will not do is use your 1st stage. It's difficult to add global NFB to it. And it is difficult to make it act as the VAS needed for the class-AB output stage.
output stage
Some of the above details are fairly concrete and apply directly to the output stage design. Working out the details of the output stage will help develop details for the earlier stage(s). So it's a good idea to start here.
To stay conservative, I'm reserving out a \$2\:\text{V}\$ margin for operating headroom. This applies to both rails (\$12\:\text{V}\$ and ground.) So there's only \$12\:\text{V}-2\cdot 2\:\text{V}=8\:\text{V}\$ left over for the output voltage swing. In essence, this means \$\pm4\:\text{V}\$ for the speaker and therefore a maximum drive current of \$500\:\text{mA}\$.
So this will be a \$1\:\text{W}\$ design (or less) and the above also helps specify the minimum current compliance for the power supply.
If I assume worst case \$\beta=30\$ for these devices, this means I have to plan for a base current of \$\ge16\frac23\:\text{mA}\$ peak. Do I want to just keep to that plan? Or do I want to augment the TIP41 and TIP42 into Sziklai pairs?
Yes, I do. Using Sziklai pairs will permit the bootstrapping choice I'll make, discussed further down. But it's not the determining reason here. Just a benefit gained.
Now, because of the decision to switch over to Sziklai pairs, and a desire for some emitter degeneration, I'm going to reserve off \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ and not \$2.0\:\text{V}\$ as overhead margins. This will allow only \$\pm3.5\:\text{V}\$ for the speaker and that fact drops the maximum output power to about \$\frac34\:\text{W}\$ into \$8\:\Omega\$. Roughly speaking (the final value for \$A_v\$ isn't worked out yet), this means the input is limited to about \$\pm100\:\text{mV}\$.
Here's the overall idea for the output stage:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Going left to right:

\$R_{11}\$, with \$R_{12}\$ and the \$R_{14}\$ potentiometer, form a voltage divider for the \$Q_5\$ VBE multiplier. \$R_{13}\$ deals with the Early Effect to form a stable collector-emitter voltage difference.
\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ reduce gain for high frequencies.
\$Q_1\$, \$Q_3\$, \$R_1\$, \$R_3\$, and \$R_5\$ form one of the two Sziklai output pairs. \$Q_2\$, \$Q_4\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_4\$, and \$R_6\$ form the other of the Sziklai output pairs.
Assuming \$\beta\ge 30\$ for \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$, and \$\beta\ge100\$ for \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$, less than \$150\:\mu\text{A}\$ of base drive will be required.

I've decided to supply \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ to pass through, quiescently, the VBE multiplier.
The VAS will sink whatever remains and isn't used in order to control the output.
The output will somehow drive the speaker as well as provide the source for the global NFB (negative feedback) used for DC bias as well as the AC gain.
Now, comes another decision. I could design a current source. That's one option. It's advantage is that there's no DC current in the speaker when there's no audio. The downside is the additional parts and, possibly, yet another impact on the margin (headroom) I need to reserve. Or I could just use one resistor to form that current source by using a bootstrap capacitor. The advantage is obvious: just one part. The downside is that the speaker itself will need to carry the DC quiescent current of \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$. That's about \$4\:\text{mV}\$ of offset voltage across the speaker when there's no audio. (Either way, I'll need that capacitor. So no difference there.)
Finally, bootstrapping (and thereby using the speaker itself as part of the current source circuit) means that the quiescent current for the class-AB stage of the amplifier becomes nill when the speaker isn't connected.
I'll take the bootstrap approach, shown below:

simulate this circuit
\$R_{15}\$ is now the current source. Imperfect. But good enough for this purpose.
The rails to these two power transistors should be starred back to the power supply (they should be isolated away from the rails used by the rest of the circuit.)
amplifier stage to drive the above class-AB stage
Now, the only thing that remains is the stage needed to take the input, accept the NFB signal, provide the rest of the AC voltage gain, and act as the VAS needed to drive this circuit properly.
This can be done entirely with just two additional BJTs.
I'll hold short of this part of the design until I hear back that I'm not already too far down the wrong path.
